# How to configure servant-multipart to allow longer file names?

Tags: haskell, multipart, type-level-computation, servant

I have some `servant-multipart` endpoint which is defined with something like `MultipartForm Mem (MultipartData Mem)`. However, this endpoint does not let me upload long-named files because of [`defaultParseRequestBodyOptions`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra-3.0.22.1/docs/Network-Wai-Parse.html#v:defaultParseRequestBodyOptions).

Somehow, I want to replace `Mem` with some `Mem'` which is associated with `noLimitParseRequestBodyOptions`, but I am not able to figure out how to do this. How do I use servant-multipart endpoints with this option from `Network.Wai.Parse`?

The `Multipart` type in the form is parametrised by `tag`, which has two implemented values in the `Servant.Multipart` module, `Tmp` and `Mem`. Now, `Mem` is an instance of `MultipartBackend` which has an associated type `MultipartBackendOptions`. I am guessing I have to modify something here to tweak the relevant `ParseRequestBodyOptions`.

Comment: can't you just change your `defaultParseRequestBodyOptions` to not have a filename length limit? Like so: `defaultParseRequestBodyOptions {prboKeyLength=Nothing}`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to define an alternative to `Mem`. Given the way servant-multipart is currently written, you do not by default have to specify any multipart options. However, you can specify them, using `serveWithContext` and a suitable `Context` that contains your options. Below is a complete example that just overrides the maximum filename length to be 512. Of particular interest is `ctxt`, which contains `multipartOpts`, our custom options.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}
import Data.Proxy
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Network.Wai.Parse
import Servant
import Servant.Multipart

type API = MultipartForm Tmp (MultipartData Tmp) :> Post '[PlainText] String

api :: Proxy API
api = Proxy

server :: MultipartData Tmp -> Handler String
server multipartData = return str

  where str = "The form was submitted with "
           ++ show nInputs ++ " textual inputs and "
           ++ show nFiles  ++ " files."
        nInputs = length (inputs multipartData)
        nFiles  = length (files multipartData)

main :: IO ()
main = run 8080 (serveWithContext api ctxt server)

  where ctxt = multipartOpts :. EmptyContext
        multipartOpts = (defaultMultipartOptions (Proxy :: Proxy Tmp))
          { generalOptions = setMaxRequestKeyLength 512 defaultParseRequestBodyOptions
          }
```

EDIT: If you're a Nix user, you can put the following at the top of the haskell file with this code, make it executable and then just launch it, letting Nix fetch all the deps etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env nix-shell
#!nix-shell -i runhaskell -p "haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (pkgs: with pkgs; [servant-server servant-multipart wai-extra warp ])"
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but I am still curious: Is it possible to actually define Mem' which is almost the same as Mem, except for the file name limit, though?

Comment: Not sure, as this is a non-backend specific type of option.